# amchart4 skipping columns in data

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I've set up a double column chart in amchart with the following:

```
data: Array(10)
0: {nothing: "22180", harvest: "22180", year: "2020"}
1: {nothing: "23354", harvest: "23887", year: "2021"}
2: {nothing: "25472", harvest: "25766", year: "2022"}
3: {nothing: "27805", harvest: "27836", year: "2023"}
4: {nothing: "30373", harvest: "30114", year: "2024"}
5: {nothing: "33200", harvest: "32622", year: "2025"}
6: {nothing: "36313", harvest: "35384", year: "2026"}
7: {nothing: "39740", harvest: "38425", year: "2027"}
8: {nothing: "43513", harvest: "41772", year: "2028"}
9: {nothing: "47668", harvest: "45458", year: "2029"}
```

However when I load the chart it only shows every other year:[Column Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C36Ae.png)

Is there an option to show all columns, or am I missing something?

```
      const chart = am4core.create("columnChart", am4charts.XYChart)
      chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

      var title = chart.titles.create();
      title.text = "Net Proceeds";
      title.fontSize = 22;
      chart.data = data

      const categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis())
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year"
      categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1
      categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
      // categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color("#A0CA92");
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 1;
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;


      const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis())
      valueAxis.title.text = "Net Proceeds (After Tax)"

      const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries())
      series.dataFields.valueY = "nothing"
      // series.dataFields.label = "${valueY}"
      series.dataFields.categoryX = "year"
      series.name = `Do Nothing Year ${new Date().getFullYear()}`

      const series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries())
      series2.dataFields.valueY = "harvest"
      series2.dataFields.label = "${valueY}"
      series2.dataFields.categoryX = "year"
      series2.name = `Harvest Gain Year ${new Date().getFullYear()}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance was not set.  Setting categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 0; fixed the issue.